# ReactJS class name changes failing when there are multiple classes on an element

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

My CSS is as follows for the sake of example

```
.menu1 { width: 50px; height:10px; background-color: black; }
.menu_change .menu1 { 
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
}
```

My react code uses an `onClick` event to change the state of a  specific property. when the property is set to true. It will add/remove the class `menu_change` to the `menu1` element respectively. This happens as expected, no problems there. The problem I am seeing is that if my elements have more than one class assigned to them, the effect is lost.

If I render the element with one or the other of the classes I will get my desired effect. Which makes no sense. So I am trying to figure  out what  the  actual issue is here

```
<div class="menu1"> WORKS </div>
<div class="menu_change"> WORKS </div>
<div class="menu_change menu1"> DOES NOT WORK </div>
```

Comment: `.menu_change .menu1` if your intentions are not wrong this will select `.menu1` classed element under `.menu_change` and there is no such element. try `<div class="menu_change"><div class="menu1">content</div></div>`

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the space between `menu_change` and `.menu1` like that

```
.menu_change.menu1 { 
background-color: darkseagreen;
-webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);}
```

Those (with and without space) are [two different selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).